# Background images resize in both width and height upon browser window resize

Tags: css

How to resize a css background image in proportion when resizing the browser window?

`#main {width:950px; height:100%; background:url(image.jpg) no-repeat center bottom}`

[image]

When browser resize images should no to go under the text, images should shrink the size to keep the same position and distance

Answer (score 2):

This is how i would do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/DpneL/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="imgCont">
    <img src="http://lorempixum.com/400/200/" alt="" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#imgCont {
    margin: 0px auto;
    min-width: 300px;
    max-width: 900px;    
    width: expression(document.body.clientWidth < 302? "300px" : document.body.clientWidth > 902? "900px" : "auto"); /* ie6 */
}

img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Proportionally it is not going to be right as you are setting a specific width with a percentage height. So try setting a width and height in according percentages.

If you are using height 100% then it's always going to go under your text as well, so that would explain that as it'll go to 100% of the browser.

You may need to experiment with setting width and height as values such as 80% etc. experiment!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css `background-size`. Have a look here: [w3c background-size](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size)

You are probably after `contain` or `cover`.

Alternatively, here is an example with an img tag: http://jsfiddle.net/jwg2s/  Try resizing your browser.

HTML

```
<div> 
    Heading text Heading text<br/>
    Heading text Heading text<br/>
    <img src="http://secondnaturearomatics.com/images/pear1.jpg" border="1" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    text-align: center;
    background: silver;
    width: 90%;
    font-size: 25px;
}
img {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: but my image is not covering the whole background. it's a small no-repeat image at center bottom

Comment: I would probably suggest that it may not be a "background image", and semantically it might be better represented by an img tag.

Comment: Perhaps the `img` tag will suit, otherwise you can add the `background-size` css to a `div` that has a width and height specified in % relative to the document/viewport.

Answer (score 0):

@jitendra; Yes you can use `background-size` property for this but instead of `cover` give value in `100%` like this

CSS:

```
#image{
    -moz-background-size: 100% 50%;
     background:url("image.jpg") no-repeat center bottom;
}
```

may be that's work for you

read these article for more: http://webdesign.about.com/od/styleproperties/p/blspbgsize.htm , http://robertnyman.com/css3/background-size/background-size.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using this jQuery plugin http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize/